# Wrong receiver after Sending EMail

Tags: outlook, outlook-2010

I'm trying to solve a really strange problem. Two Outlook Clients are showing the wrong reciever after sending a E-Mail (jon.doe@example.com).

His Contact Details are:

```
Jon Doe
0012 3456 7891
jon.doe@example.com
```

but after sending in the "To:" field the Name Max Musterman is listed there.

Max Musterman has following Information:

```
Max Mustermann
0019 8765 4321
```

After some testing we found out that even when you did not send the email and just enter the jon.doe@example.com into the "To:" field it is associated with Max Mustermann but they don't share ANY information.

Someone some ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Double click on Max Mustermann if shown once you enter jon.doe@example.com, then on the General tab and the E-mail Addresses tab (under SMTP:) what email address is shown there? If it shows jon.doe@example.com, then this means jon.doe@example.com is Max Mustermann and Max Mustermann's email address is jon.doe@example.com.